# Android App on Local Server?

Tags: android

I have an android app, which I run on my emulator & my local server. Now, I want the android app on my mobile, (which I managed to get ) to run with my local server. So, app would be on my android device & the back end server will be on my local machine.

So, when I tried to connect the app to the server using the URI http://10.0.2.2:8080/JSPPATH
i got connection timed out, and when I use the URI as http://localhost:8080/JSPPATH then i get connection refused.

How could I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone is not in the same network as your computer. You need to start the server and bind it to an external IP, and set that IP in the code where you make the connection.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply ... How do i bind my local server to an external ip ?... it ip is 127.0.0.1 & that's wat i configured in the app as well ... I have now ensured that both the mobile & the server are using the same network ...

Comment: depdens on your server... it should be something like start-server -b 127.0.0.1 ...

Comment: thank u for ur reply. Well i did wat u said. I got my mobile of the same network as my local server. My local server is binded to the IP : 127.0.0.1 . I configured the same in my android app. However, it did not work out. 

Kindly tell me if I have missed out on something. I everything I did was as u said, they could u suggest something else to solve this problem .

Comment: are you sure that 127.0.0.1 is your PC ip address? and the mobile is connected throught Wi-Fi to your network?

Comment: Hey i tried that too. I'm showing u the command

run -c Mobile -b 127.0.0.1   ... it still does not work ..... i'm getting connection refused in the apps logs ....

Comment: Thanks a ton mate .... It worked ... Frankly , i did not properly understand ur first post ... I understood it now , after doing some reading ... And it worked ... Thank u very much once again